# Get App Id of same type of apps in multiple Podio Workspace

Tags: php, podio

I want to get App Id of same type of apps multiple Podio Work space.

Example scenario: I have two work space. Both work space have Deliverable app. I want to get App Id of Deliverable app of both Work space.

```
PodioApp::get_all( $attributes = array() );
```

I can get apps by above api request. But i can't track if it is Deliverable app or not.

Comment: Please provide a little more context. What is the criteria for the two apps to be identical? Just the name? Bear in mind that the apps can be altered independently of each other.

In general if you want to find two somehow-equivalent apps in two workspaces you can get all apps in space A and  B and then loop over the two sets and compare.

Comment: My requirement is to display items of an App (eg Deliverable) in Space A and B on a single page. I know that I cannot take the name as an identifier to compare the apps.
Is there any id or something that a Apps share in common, then only I can compare these apps in Space A and B.

Answer (score 1):

If the app in space B is cloned from the app in space A, then the app in space B will have a field called original that will hold the ID of the app in space A.

You can try to clone an app in Podio and then go here https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349 and fetch the app of the newly cloned app to verify.

```
 {
   ...
   "app_id": 18245877,
   "original": 18166054,
   ...
 }
```

If you just happen to have constructed 2 apps that share the same fields, then they have no such relation and comparing them is a hell of a harder task.